Difference between AWS::IAM::Policy and AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
I have more than 10 lambdas. I am managing the infrastructure using sam template.
I have defined Function resources for these lambdas. There are some common permissions required by these lambdas - cloudwatch, xray. Each lambda again require it's own specific permissions.
Like Lambda1 might require permission for S3, Lambda2 for ParameterStore.
So, to manage these permissions for the lambdas, I have decided to create inline policy along each Function resource with specific permissions. And define a Policy Resource with common permissions for all lambdas and refer that in each inline lambda policy.
When I am defining the separate Policy Resource, I am confused to use Type either AWS::IAM::Policy or AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy. What is the difference between two? What is useful in my use case?
And also please suggest how can I refer this Policy Resource in inline policy of each lambda.

It would help if you could add a simplified, non-sensitive variant of your SAM template with the function declaration and its current policies, so that someone can see what you're currently doing.

When we define policy as
AWS::IAM::Policy it is required to associate it with any user/role
AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy it is not required to do so here

AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy is managed and provided by AWS and AWS::IAM::Policy is something you create
For example There is ManagedPolicy named AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore
Which is an AWS managed policy  which is readily availlable for use.Likewise there are number of ManagedPolicies for common usescases provided by AWS

Under ManagedPolicies there are both AWS, Customer Managed policies. So, the policy I am defining can also be referred as Managed Policy I guess.

Yes, there are customer managed policies and AWS managed policies.

@jarmod could you please help to answer my query
